# "R cannot open because of a problem"

Tags: macos, applications, install, r

I've installed R 3.6.3 on a Mac OS X El Capitan, but when I try to open it I get a pop-up saying "R cannot open because of a problem".
The message is not in English, but it's the same as this one (replace python2.7 by R):

[image]

I've tried with older versions, I rebooted the computer, I uninstalled it and installed it again, but I keep getting the same message.
FYI, I had anaconda installed before and I also tried uninstalling it.

Comment: It says *python* can’t open.  El Capitan comes with v2.7 so it shoukd be working.  You said you “tried older versions.”  Older versions of python or R?  Can you elaborate on what you’ve attempted thus far?  Also, issue the command `which python` and `python --version`.  Post to your question

Comment: @Allan The screenshot says python only because OP says they got an English language picture off the internet of an equivalent message

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.  Your explanation helped